# sort given string alphabetically and return letter for letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I basically want to alphabetically sort a given string and output letter for letter via inline-function...

```
create function dbo.SortStringLetter4Letter (
  @key varchar(64)
) returns table 
as 
return select ...
```

And I want to call up the function like this:

```
select * 
  from dbo.SortStringLetter4Letter('TEST');
go
```

And get a result like this:

```
id           Sorted
----------- -------- 
1           E        
2           S        
3           T        
4           T
```

Anybody got an idea for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do;

```
create or alter function dbo.SortStringLetter4Letter (
  @key varchar(64)
) returns table 
as 
return 

WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM Numbers 
        WHERE Number < Len(@key)
)
Select 
    id = Number, Sorted = SUBSTRING(@Key, Number, 1)
from Numbers


GO

Select * from dbo.SortStringLetter4Letter('test') order by sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I worked out:

```
drop function if exists dbo.LetterForLetter;

create function dbo.LetterForLetter (
  @key varchar(128)
) returns @chars table (# int, character char)
as 
begin
    insert into @chars 
    select #,
           substring(@key, #, 1) "character"               
      from Numbers
   where # <= len(@key)
     and # > 0
 return

end;
go

select * 
  from dbo.LetterForLetter('TEST');
go
```

The table Numbers is just filled with numbers btw. that I used to give the keys an ID